# How do I show only two digits after decimal

Tags: android

I am getting Value for mGTotal like: 179.257856

but now I just want to show only two digits after decimal, like:  179.25

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (Constants.mItem_Detail.size() == 0) 
        {
            return;
        }

        Double mGTotal = Double.parseDouble(Constants.mItem_Detail.get(0).get(SingleProductActivity.KEY_TOTAL));
        for (int i = 1; i < Constants.mItem_Detail.size(); i++) 
        {   
        mGTotal = mGTotal + Double.parseDouble(Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i).get(SingleProductActivity.KEY_TOTAL));
        }
        mGrandTotal = String.valueOf(mGTotal);
        mTxtViewGrandTotal.setText(mGrandTotal);
        myTextVeiwGrandTotal.setText(mGrandTotal);
        mTotal = String.valueOf(Constants.mItem_Detail.size());
        mItems.setText(mTotal);

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close to your answer, I guess below line will work for you:

```
 mTxtViewGrandTotal.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(mGTotal));
```

and complete method should look like this:

```
   @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (Constants.mItem_Detail.size() == 0) 
        {
            return;
        }

        Double mGTotal = Double.parseDouble(Constants.mItem_Detail.get(0).get(SingleProductActivity.KEY_TOTAL));
        for (int i = 1; i < Constants.mItem_Detail.size(); i++) 
        {   
        mGTotal = mGTotal + Double.parseDouble(Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i).get(SingleProductActivity.KEY_TOTAL));
        }
        mGrandTotal = String.valueOf(mGTotal);
        mTxtViewGrandTotal.setText(mGrandTotal);
        myTextVeiwGrandTotal.setText(mGrandTotal);
        mTxtViewGrandTotal.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(mGTotal));
        mTotal = String.valueOf(Constants.mItem_Detail.size());
        mItems.setText(mTotal);

}
```

Answer (score 7):

use [`Decimalformat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.println(df.format("179.257856"));// which gives result as 179.25
```